# When to delete allocated memory of returned value

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

When I delete the memory of b for the given function "lowerCaseWord(char* a)"? I need to return the value of b, so I can't delete it before the line "return b;". Do I need to use another variable? Or does the compiler delete it alone(even though its not good programming)?

```
char* lowerCaseWord(char* a)
{
    char *b=new char[strlen(a)];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        b[i] = tolower(a[i]);   
    }
    return b;
```

}

Comment: @Moo-Juice That _is_ C++. Try compiling it with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @zenith, oh yes - it'll will compile with a C++ compiler - as will C.  My point was, you wouldn't do that if you were writing C++ as opposed to, say, C :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `delete[]` it outside the function by yourself, even though it's not a good practice. Such as:

```
char* rtv = lowerCaseWord(a);
// process with rtv
// ...
delete[] rtv;
```

It's better to use [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) to avoid manual memory management, such as:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> lowerCaseWord(char* a)
{
    ...
}
```

then

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> rtv = lowerCaseWord(a);
// process with rtv
// ...
```

As @FrerichRaabe pointed, basically using raw pointer is not a good idea, you may want to use `std::string` directly.

Comment: Of course, if you're willing to use `std::shared_ptr` you may just as well operate on plain `std::string` objects in the first place.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<char>` is for a single `char`, no?

Comment: Right, sorry about causing confusion. I think you'll need to use a special deleter, but the type would be the same as in your original code. However, this doesn't make it clear to the user that the thing manages a dynamically allocated array. You might be better off with a unique_ptr, but I think the real solution is to use an `std::string`.

Comment: `const char *a` surely ?

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function is wrong

```
char* lowerCaseWord(char* a)
                    ^^^^
{
    char *b=new char[strlen(a)];
                     ^^^^^^^^^
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
         ^^^
    {
        b[i] = tolower(a[i]);   
                       ^^^^
    }
    return b;
}
```

It gets a string but does not return a string because the new character array does not include the terminating zero.

And it can not deal with constant objects as for example string literals. And moreover it confuses users because they will think that their original string is changed in the function.

Also standard function `tolower` considers characters casted to `unsigned char`.

That is according to the C Standard (7.4 Character handling )

> 1. ...In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be
>      representable as an **unsigned char** or shall equal the value of the
>      macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, **the behavior is
>      undefined**.

And the type of the variable `i` should be `size_t` because iit is the type that has the return value of the function `strlen`.

You have to write

```
char* lowerCaseWord( const char *a )
{
    char *b = new char[std::strlen( a ) + 1];

    size_t i = 0;
    do
    {
        b[i] = std::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( a[i] ) );
    } while ( a[i++] );   

    return b;
}
```

The function design supposes that it is the client of the function that has to free the memory pointed to by the returned pointer.

Comment: Casting to `unsigned char`? That's worse than the original. It will just hide the incorrect input.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername You should read the description of the function tolower. It is a requirement of the function.

Comment: You should look at the function signature. It accepts `int`. The behavior will be undefined if the input is out of `unsigned char` scope. If the user has provided incorrect input, casting it to `unsigned char` won't fix it but rather hide the original bug and make it harder to debug.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername In my opinion there is clear written in the Standard that "In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be
representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the
argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: That has no relation to your suggested solution. The function should either assume that the input is correct or treat it in place if it's incorrect without some weird attempt to "fix it" to avoid undefined `tolower` behavior. Handling can be, for example, an assertion or throwing an exception or returning NULL as an output.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername For example Russian characters in the extended ASCII table have negative values. Without casting the integer ptomotion will be applied to the argument and it will have negative value of type int. In this case instead of to get a valid result the function behaviour will be undefined.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I suppose that the argument is used as an index in a table of 256 characters. And the only check that the function shall do is to check whether the value is equal to EOF.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername So the integer promotion shall be applied to a value of type unsigned char. Otherwise you will get an invalid index in the table.

Comment: Russian characters don't have negative values. They're out of `signed char` range so the values wrap around to negative. If the input contains russian characters it shouldn't be represented by `signed char`s in the first place, it falls in the "incorrect input" category. And you shouldn't assume anything regarding the implemenatation of `tolower`, especially since it's dependent on the localization that is used (i.e., it's not necessary enough to do -'0' for conversion).

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I am sorry I do not understand what "out of signed char range" means. Type char may behave as type signed char and if the sign bit is set then the value is negative. The type signed char knows nothing about Russian letters.:) There is no such a notion as "out of range of signed char".for values stored in signed char.:) If to follow your logic then some characters have some own undefined type.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername And it is me who  assumes nothing else except what is written in the C Standard. If the C Standard says that the value of the argument shall be represented as unsigned character I have to supply such a value. Otherwise the behaviour is undefined or I will never get the lower case of a Russian letter.:)

Comment: Extended ASCII table includes charactes with values in the range 128-255, which is obviously out of the range of signed char which represents -128-127 range. The fact that both signed and unsigned chars occupy the same amount of space has nothing to do with their semantic definition. If I have a string of russian characters, I won't store it in a char* string, even if it's possible to treat each character as an unsigned value.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The integer promotion nothing knows about Russian characters. It takes into account only whether the sign bit is set or not. So for negative values after the integer promotion the argument of the function will not have a value that is representable as unsigned char. So the function will have undefined behaviour and you will never get the lower case of a Russian letter.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Consider the following function definition. int tolower( int c ) { if ( c != EOF ) c = ( unsigned char )SomeTable[c]; return c; } It is entirely a correct function definition according to the C Standard.  It will return undefined value for a Russian letter because the SomeTable has only 256 characters.

Comment: So you enter a wrong input in the first place (negative values) and expect the standard library to behave according to your expectations? In your *specific private case* the casting might resolve the problem, but in the general case it won't. E.g., the user might work with latin characters only and doesn't expect for `tolower` to yield a sensible result for ascii codes that happen to correspond to russian characters. Casting will just hide the problem. Also, in the extended ASCII table most of the characters don't correspond to letters, with or without russian letters.

Comment: BTW, in your example the casting to unsigned char will ensure that the table isn't accessed with out-of-bounds index.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername This ensure that the behaviour will be undefined as it is written in the C Standard if the value of the argument is not representable as a value of an object of type unsigned character. It is a strictly conforming function definition according to the C Standard.

Comment: True, but table size of 256 has nothing to do with it

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername With what?! According to the C Standard the valid values of the argument are the values in the range UCHAR_MIN - UCHAR_MAX. So the table deals with the valid values. Otherwise if the user provided an invalid value the behaviour of the function is undefined. And the Standard says clearly about this.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I misread your last example. Ignore my comment regarding the table access. Nevertheless, it was just a side comment. The real problem remains as I stated in the comment just before that one.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is indeed C++ code, but it is not *genuine* C++ code.

Recent C++11 (or C++14) tend to discourage writing such things. You probably want to use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idioms, [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), `std::string`-s,

And of course, in languages and programs doing explicit manual memory allocation, you need conventions and disciplines to define who and when should a pointer be released. With your code, you need at least a comment in a header file saying who and how and when the result of your `lowerCaseWord` function should be released.

I believe that you should at least read things about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) and [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) (at least for concepts and terminology).

Answer (score 1):

Smart pointers are a solution, but I would recommend to change your function to:

```
void lowerCaseWord(char* destination, const char* source);
```

With this definition, the caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the memory for the destination string. This has the advantage that the destination can be on the stack, on the heap, or even a member of a class/struct. This is not possible if the memory is always allocated by the function.

`strcpy` and friends are also defined like that.